# Loading a semicolon-separated string into an array in shell scripting

Tags: shell

i have a test file. and suppose content is like this. i want to put this into an array separated by "semicolon" in shell script

> History is the discovery, collection, organization, analysis, and presentation of information about past events. History can also mean a continuous typically; chronological record of important or public events or of a particular trend or institution. Scholars who write about history are called historians. It is a field of knowledge which uses a narrative to examine and analyse the sequence of events; and it sometimes attempts to objectively investigate the patterns of cause and effect that determine events;

expected output:

`array[0]` should contain:

> History is the discovery, collection, organization, analysis, and presentation of information about past events. History can also mean a continuous typically;

`array[1]` should contain:

> chronological record of important or public events or of a particular trend or institution. Scholars who write about history are called historians. It is a field of knowledge which uses a narrative to examine and analyse the sequence of events;

`array[3]` should contain:

> and it sometimes attempts to objectively investigate the patterns of cause and effect that determine events;

like this way.... what will be the logic....

Comment: `array[1]` doesn't print the second element of the array named `array`. Do you mean `echo "${array[1]}` should print that?

Comment: yes... it would be ${array[0]} then ${array[1]} ...like that

Comment: BTW, normal POSIX sh doesn't support arrays at all, so I assume you want a different shell for this -- ksh? bash? Can you specify your exact platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the below is written for bash, not POSIX sh (which does not support arrays).

---

If you load content like so:

```
array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d ';' content; do
  array+=( "${content};" )
done <input.txt
```

...then

```
echo "First section:  ${array[0]}"
echo "Second section: ${array[1]}"
```

...and so forth will behave as intended. This is because the bash `read -d` extension treats the next character as the end-of-record delimiter, such that reads proceed up to that point.

---

For more on reading file content in bash, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?").